# vscode won't run on my laptop while i'm offline

Tags: visual-studio-code, offline

vscode won't run on my win10 64bit os while i'm not connected to internet! as soon as I connect to internet it open's. 
I have tried a lot to find the problem. even I have reinstalled my windows but it doesn't work. 
what is the problem? pls help me if u know the answer

Answer (score 1):

See this issue [vscode won't run offline](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7570).   There is a workaround posted there: [comment: loopback adapter](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7570#issuecomment-454806257).

Later comment in that thread indicates it may have been fixed in an insider's build of windows 10.

Comment: Thx alot. The problem was related to 1809 os version update. Today i updated my os again and my problem was solved after new update